# How to write a multiple argument environment within a newcommand?

Tags: macros, environments, optional-arguments, environment-variables, technical-environment

In my custom class file, I have a command that generates a new environment:

```
\newcommand{\MakeThEnv}[4]{

\DefaultFrame{#1}{#2}

\theoremstyle{#3}
\newtheorem{#2T}{#4}

\newenvironment{#2}{\begin{#2Box}\begin{#2T}}{\end{#2T}\end{#2Box}}
```

where `\DefaultFrame{color}{blabla}` creates the environment `blablaBox` in the `color` color. But for another purpose, I made a 'multiple items' environment command

```
\newcommand{\MakeMultEnv}[4]
{    
  \DefaultFrameMult{#1}{#2}

  \theoremstyle{#3}
  \newtheorem*{#2Ts}{#4}

  \newenvironment{#2s}
  {
    \begin{#2Boxs}
    \begin{#2Ts}\hfill
    \begin{enumerate}[wide, label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
  } 
  {
    \end{enumerate}\end{#2Ts}\end{#2Boxs}
  }
}
```

I'd like to add some optional arguments to the `#2s` environment (for example, add a title and add a preamble before `\hfill`, and make it optional). My dream is to make somthing like this :

```
\newenvironment{blablas}[2][1={},2=\hfill]{
  \begin{blablaBoxs}
    \begin{blablaTs}[#1]{#2}
      \begin{enumerate}[wide, label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]} 
 {\end{enumerate}\end{blablaTs}\end{blablaBoxs}}
```

(The `[1={},2=\hfill]` thing comes from the `xargs` package.) But as you can see, replace `blabla` by `#2` seems to be a problem...

Here's a reproductible example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\DefaultFrame[2]{
\newmdenv[
skipabove=2pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=#1,
linewidth=4pt,
]{#2Box}}

\newcommand\DefaultMultFrame[2]{
\newmdenv[
skipabove=2pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=#1,
linewidth=4pt,
]{#2Boxs}}

\newcommand{\MakeThEnv}[3]{

\DefaultFrame{#1}{#2}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{#2T}{#3}

\newenvironment{#2}{\begin{#2Box}\begin{#2T}}{\end{#2T}\end{#2Box}}
}

\newcommand{\MakeMultThEnv}[3]{

\DefaultMultFrame{#1}{#2}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{#2Ts}{#3}
\newenvironment{#2s}
{\begin{#2Boxs}\begin{#2Ts}\hfill\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}\end{#2Ts}\end{#2Boxs}}
}
\definecolor{maincolor}{HTML}{1d3557}
\MakeThEnv{maincolor}{theo}{Theorem}
\MakeMultThEnv{maincolor}{theo}{Theorems}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}    
\begin{theo}[Me]
    A theorem by me.
\end{theo}

\begin{theos}
    \item First theorem.
    \item Second theorem.
\end{theos}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

I'd like a command that makes the `theos` environment but where I can for some usage add a title and a preamble before the `enumerate`, like this:

```
\begin{theos}[Me]{Let $x$ a thing.}
    \item First theorem.
    \item Second theorem.
\end{theos}
```

in order to get this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arguments to your `\newenvironment`, for example

```
\newenvironment{#2s}[2][]
```

defines the environment with one optional argument, which is by default empty, and one required argument.  You then refer to these arguments in the environment definition by using `##1` and `##2`; note the use of double `#`.  For example

```
\newenvironment{#2s}[2][]
{\begin{#2Boxs}\begin{#2Ts}[##1]##2\hfill\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}\end{#2Ts}\end{#2Boxs}}
```

In your example code this gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\DefaultFrame[2]{
\newmdenv[
skipabove=2pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=#1,
linewidth=4pt,
]{#2Box}}

\newcommand\DefaultMultFrame[2]{
\newmdenv[
skipabove=2pt,
skipbelow=2pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=#1,
linewidth=4pt,
]{#2Boxs}}

\newcommand{\MakeThEnv}[3]{

\DefaultFrame{#1}{#2}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{#2T}{#3}

\newenvironment{#2}{\begin{#2Box}\begin{#2T}}{\end{#2T}\end{#2Box}}
}

\newcommand{\MakeMultThEnv}[3]{

\DefaultMultFrame{#1}{#2}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{#2Ts}{#3}
\newenvironment{#2s}[2][]
{\begin{#2Boxs}\begin{#2Ts}[##1]##2\hfill\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}\end{#2Ts}\end{#2Boxs}}
}
\definecolor{maincolor}{HTML}{1d3557}
\MakeThEnv{maincolor}{theo}{Theorem}
\MakeMultThEnv{maincolor}{theo}{Theorems}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Me]
    A theorem by me.
\end{theo}

\begin{theos}[Me]{}
    \item First theorem.
    \item Second theorem.
\end{theos}

\begin{theos}[Me]{Let \( x \) be a thing.}
    \item First theorem.
    \item Second theorem.
\end{theos}

\end{document}
```

If you want to do fancier argument parsing, you could investigate the new `xparse` derived commands such as `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.  See the `usrguide` documentation, https://ctan.org/pkg/usrguide.